# Why was load class cache deprecated in Symfony in php7

Tags: symfony, php-7

I noticed one commit [13da5dca](https://github.com/symfony/demo/commit/13da5dca05961d4c50dcf68dabf85416fe89ca5b) in the [Symfony demo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo.git), with this as part of diff code:

```
-include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
+if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
+    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
+}

-$kernel->loadClassCache();
+if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
+    $kernel->loadClassCache();
+}
```

The commit comment is: **Fix error with class redeclaration: Do not load cache files on PHP 7**

I know it's a fix commit, but I want know why! So, I suspect it's a PHP 7 new feature or otherwise, and I'd like to find it out.

There are many resource I found:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/1030
- https://github.com/symfony/demo/pull/414
- https://github.com/symfony/demo/issues/411
- https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/components/class_loader.html

But no explanation, just how to fix the error it causes, all of them.
Can somebody explain?

Comment: It's a good question.  I just assumed that php 7 improved code caching made it superfluous.  You might have a better chance of getting a more informed answer on the [Symfony Slack chat](https://symfony.com/community).

Comment: Thank you, It's a great way.

Answer (score 3):

You can find your answer in [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20668) and in [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/20735).

As answered by Cerad, with PHP 7 it's faster not to use the bootstrap cache.

Comment: I've read that PR before, and I know it's just a benching result. But It's not explain why PHP 7 is faster in this situation.

Comment: In the second comment of the issue, [stof answered it partially](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20668#issuecomment-263316522). You can also check this [composer PR](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5174).